# How Start a window with Main() in Console Project.?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, console, console-application

I have a console project, but now I need to put an user interface on. So I'm using the 3 tier model (presentation, business, access data).

In my method `Main()` I call to presentation layer (like app in Window form or Wpf), so, in the presentation layer is the interaction with user through CONSOLE.

Now I add a window called "UserInterface.xaml" in the presentation layer to use instead of console. Because should be with INTERFACE not console.

I have observed that in MainWindow the called is with MainWindow.Show();

But I don't know how to call my "UserInterface.xaml", because has no .Show() method.

This is my method Main:

```
public static void Main()
{
  MainWindow.Show(); // THIS IS WITH MainWindow.xaml
  UserInterface.???  // THIS IS MY CASE WITH UserInterface.xaml
}
```

So can somebody tell me how I can call my window from the Main method??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a Window since Programm class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073658/open-a-window-since-programm-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely got started with the wrong project template.  To make a WPF window visible and interactive, you have to follow the rules for a UI thread.  Which includes marking the main thread of your app as an STA thread and pumping a message loop.  Like this:

```
class Program {
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main() {
        var app = new Application();
        app.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
}
```

Beware that Application.Run() is a blocking call, it will not return until the user closes the main window.  This is a rather inevitable consequence of the way Windows works.

Comment: yes, in my case I make this: var app = new UserInterface();
                             app.Run(new Program()); but not recognizing the .Run

Comment: Right, you got that backwards.

Comment: Now I open the window whith [STAThread], but closed again!, why occurs this? what cain I do??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `UserInterface` is really a window, this should work:

```
var window = new UserInterface();
window.Show();
```

Comment: not recognizing the  .Show();... and UserInterface is a Window.

Comment: You are going to have to show us more code in that case, because if `UserInterface` were a `Window`, it would have a `Show()` method. How does the source code for `UserInterface` look like?

Comment: this is part of the class UserInterface, how you see is a normal window:                                              public class UserInterface: Window
    {
        public event EventHandler<OptionSelectedEventArg> OptionSelected;

        public void SetPathCharger2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }

Comment: @ale, then `UserInterface` *does have* `Show()` method, unless `Window` is not `System.Windows.Window` in your code.