# Open a Window since Programm class?

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, console-application, 3-tier

I have a console application. So I need Open a Window called "UserInterface.xaml" this is a Window.

I my class Program I have this:

```
class Program
{
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {        
            var userInterface = new UserInterface();
            userInterface .Show();
}
```

The problem is when the UserInterface.xaml is opened but then is closed immediately. And I need it for capture some data from user.

this is my class UserInterface:

```
public partial class UserInterface: Window
    {       

        public UserInterface()
        {                
            InitializeComponent();
        }

........
}
```

How can I make the UserInterface window stay opened?

Comment: Do not create a Console application if you want to show a window. You need a message pump in order to do that. Start with the template to make sure it gets things right. Console applications are completely different.

Comment: @Cody, there's no reason you can't show GUI from a console app. .NET supports this quite well.

Comment: "Can", of course, is different from "should". There's a reason the two projects have different names: they have explicitly different design and architecture goals. It's possible to let the rich and versatile functionality of the .NET Framework become a hindrance, rather than a virtue. This may well be one of those cases. I'm suggesting to seriously reconsider whether this should be a console app in the first place, considering what you're asking to do, not suggesting that it's impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Start a window with Main() in Console Proyect.??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065618/how-start-a-window-with-main-in-console-proyect)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ShowDialog() method instead.

```
    UserInterface userInterface  = new UserInterface();
    userInterface.ShowDialog();
```

It will block until the form is manually or programmatically closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to refine your Main() as below:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var userInterface  = new UserInterface();

    System.Windows.Application app = new System.Windows.Application();
    app.Run(userInterface);
}
```